# Sending crowdsale tokens to investors with ethersJS

Tags: ethers.js, crowdsale

In my crowdsale contract I have provided a claim function for investors to claim their tokens (PULL). No issues with that.

```
function claim() external nonReentrant {
    claimInvestor(msg.sender);
}
```

However, I would like to provide functionality also to deliver their tokens to investors from the contract admin (PUSH). The first idea would be something like this:

```
function claimAll() external nonReentrant onlyOwner {
    for (uint i = 0; i < investors.length; i++) {
        claimInvestor(investors[i]);
    }
}
```

However, this seems to be a bad practice because the unbounded loop.

So I plan to apply [Amortisation of Work](https://blog.b9lab.com/getting-loopy-with-solidity-1d51794622ad) and move this loop to client side by providing in the contract:

```
function claimAddress(address investor) external nonReentrant onlyOwner {
    claimInvestor(investor);
}
```

then I would need from client side JS something like

```
for (var i = 0; i < investors.length; i++) {
    await ICO_CONTRACT?.claimAddress(investors[i]).then(processClaimSuccess).catch(handleError);
}
```

Questions:

- Is this rationale ok? WDYT?
- How can I run this client side code in ethersJS without opening metamask to sign every single transaction for each investor? Can I sign to bypass metamask? Can I batch all in a single transaction?

---

Update1: As I read here, it depends on the wallet that holds the private keys used to sign the transaction. If is a metamask account, metamask should be opened. So, for my case, first thing would be to change the owner of the contract to an account in a wallet that allows signing programmatically.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/117226/94894

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use additional mapping which will store the number of tokens each investor is entitled to

```
mapping(address => uint256) public entitledTokens;
```

And rather them sending them one by one just make the smart contract in such a way that they can claim their tokens themselves which will be a much more efficient and better approach

```
function claimTokens() public {
   erc20.transferFrom(owner, msg.sender, entitledTokens[msg.sender])
}
```

Comment: I do this as well but many tokens will be unclaimed so I want to provide an alternative mechanism that we can control. This is the PULL approach I mentioned at the beginning of my post